# Is it possible to run pyinstaller using the modules in the created dist folder on another machine?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have created an application that was bundled into a single folder using pyinstaller with the --onefolder command.

If I was to share the folder with some one, who doesn't have all the modules downloaded, could they use the files and modules in the the folder to run pyinstaller?

How would that be possible?

I have tried add to add all the files in the folder using --add-data but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This is the intention of Pyinstaller, yes. Bear in mind that any compiled application will be platform dependent. So you can only run on the same OS that you build on.